# The Last Supper

Tags: riddle

Run and hide, the hunt has begun!
Witches burn; no trial, no fun.
Their hammer has struck a decisive blow,
Letting little live and nothing grow.

Their minds are made, their fates are sealed,
Get away now, or your art be killed.
Abandon ship! This vessel has sunk.
They will be left with a pitiful chunk.

When the ashes have settled, nothing left to attack.
Did they make the right choice? We are not coming back!

Who are they?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19142/another-home-for-challenges

Comment: I wish I could +10 this question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are:

> puzzling.stackexchange.com users and moderators!

No need to explain that. But anyway:

> Run and hide, the hunt has begun!
>   Witches burn; no trial, no fun.

> This topic: [Is it time for us to disallow challenge-only questions?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/puzzling-se-where-we-hate-fun-its-time-to-disallow-challenge-questions)

> Their hammer has struck a decisive blow,
>   Letting little live and nothing grow.

> The party is over.

> Their minds are made, their fates are sealed,

> They won't change their mind. They "democratically" decided that, because everything is always democratic here.

> Get away now, or your art be killed.
>   Abandon ship! This vessel has sunk.

> The last to go, please turn off the lights!

> They will be left with a pitiful chunk.
>   When the ashes have settled, nothing left to attack.
>   Did they make the right choice? We are not coming back!

> What will be left in this site? Just an evacuated ghost town. Exactly what SE sites are supposed to not be.

Comment: 'They won't change their mind. They "democratically" decided that because everything is always democratic here.' - I knew there was a reason I wanted to see this :D

Answer (score 0):

I think the **solution** clearly is

> [found here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80752/puzzle-and-riddle-challenges)

Comment: Or [here](http://www.puzzling.xyz).